# Organizing the output of shell script into tables within the text file

Tags: shell, unix, text-files

I am working with a unix shell script which have an output of script like below code:

```
    EVENT DATE: 2019-05-12


TrapLogId Severity EventTime Model Description

     1604 [major]  05:59:50     14 Network Interface Down: service 1-16
     1605 [major]  05:59:51     14 Network Interface Down: service 1-15



EVENT DATE: 2019-05-13


TrapLogId Severity  EventTime Model Description

     1619 [minor]   07:58:50     30 Delayed Subscriber Mapping
     1620 [minor]   08:03:49     79 Failed Reload: File syntax
     1621 [clear]   08:04:49     79 Failed Reload Cleared: File syntax
     1622 [clear]   08:28:50     30 Delayed Subscriber Mapping Cleared


EVENT DATE: 2019-05-15


TrapLogId Severity EventTime Model Description

     1627 [minor]  01:43:58     22 Misconfigured Network Awareness: 10.1.17.0/24
     1628 [clear]  01:48:58     22 Misconfigured Network Awareness Cleared
```

Im trying to organize it into table like this format :

```
EVENT DATE    TrapLogId     Severity     EventTime   Model  Description

2019-05-12    1604          [major]      05:59:50    14     Network Interface Down: service 1-16
2019-05-12    1605          [major]      05:59:51    14     Network Interface Down: service 1-15
2019-05-13    1619          [minor]      07:58:50    30     Delayed Subscriber Mapping
2019-05-13    1620          [minor]      08:03:49    79     Failed Reload: File syntax
2019-05-13    1621          [clear]      08:04:49    79     Failed Reload Cleared: File syntax
2019-05-13    1622          [clear]      08:28:50    30     Delayed Subscriber Mapping Cleared
2019-05-15    1627          [minor]      01:43:58    22     Misconfigured Network Awareness: 10.1.17.0/24
2019-05-15    1628          [clear]      01:48:58    22     Misconfigured Network Awareness Cleared
```

how to parse it ? how to export it into table using shell ?

the code i want to organize into table has:

```
event date 1
header
content 1

event date 2
header
content 2
```

etc

i want it as

```
event date (as part of the header) header
content 1
content 2
content 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your script to:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
        print "EVENT DATE    TrapLogId     Severity     EventTime   Model  Description"
        print
    }
    /EVENT DATE/ {date=$3}
    match($3, "[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]") {
        printf( "%-14s%-14s%-13s%-12s%-3s", date, $1, $2, $3, $4)
        for(i=1;i<=4;i++) $i=""
        print
    }
    '
```

Comment: Looks pretty darn close. Any reason you prefer `match` over `$3 ~ "[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"`?

Comment: @oguzismail `print` (with no argument) in a BEGIN clause prints a single line feed.  `print` in an action block prints the current line.  `print ""` in the BEGIN clause would be identical to merely using `print`, but `print ""` in the action clause would be completely different.  I'm not sure what the point of your question is.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, I guess I just think of ~ as a perl operator and usually forget that I can use it in awk.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yep, I guess it all depends what you learned first. I had to go lookup `match` just to make sure to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t"; dateTag="EVENT DATE" }

{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }

/^[^0-9]/ {
    if ( $0 ~ dateTag ) {
        date = $NF
    }
    else if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
        numCols = NF
        gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,OFS)

        print dateTag, $0
    }
}

/^[0-9]/ {
    rest = desc = $0
    sub("([[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+){"(NF-numCols)+1"}$","",rest)
    sub("^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"numCols-1"}","",desc)
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,OFS,rest)

    print date, rest, desc
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
EVENT DATE  TrapLogId  Severity  EventTime  Model  Description
2019-05-12  1604       [major]   05:59:50   14     Network Interface Down: service 1-16
2019-05-12  1605       [major]   05:59:51   14     Network Interface Down: service 1-15
2019-05-13  1619       [minor]   07:58:50   30     Delayed Subscriber Mapping
2019-05-13  1620       [minor]   08:03:49   79     Failed Reload: File syntax
2019-05-13  1621       [clear]   08:04:49   79     Failed Reload Cleared: File syntax
2019-05-13  1622       [clear]   08:28:50   30     Delayed Subscriber Mapping Cleared
2019-05-15  1627       [minor]   01:43:58   22     Misconfigured Network Awareness: 10.1.17.0/24
2019-05-15  1628       [clear]   01:48:58   22     Misconfigured Network Awareness Cleared
```